# Tikz fit inner sep seperate values for all 4 directions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Assume I have two nodes in tikz and I want to highlight them via tikz fit.
If I want to add a margin I can use `inner sep = xpt`, however, all 4 sites are increased by the same value. Is it possible to specify for each side a separate value, e.g., `inner sep = x1pt x2pt x3pt x4pt`?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={text=gray},node distance=2cm]
\node[,draw] (n1) {hello};
\node[right of=n1,draw] (n2) {hello2};
\node[draw,fit=(n1) (n2),inner sep=10pt] (t31) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example of desired outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This comes with a key `fit margins` that does what I think you want. You can use it as e.g. in

```
\node[draw,fit margins={left=3pt,right=12pt,bottom=3pt,top=8pt},fit=(n1) (n2)] (t31) {};
```

to obtain

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\tikzset{fit margins/.style={/tikz/afit/.cd,#1,
    /tikz/.cd,
    inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/left}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/right},
    inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/top}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/bottom},
    xshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/left}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/right},
    yshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/bottom}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/top}},
    afit/.cd,left/.initial=2pt,right/.initial=2pt,bottom/.initial=2pt,top/.initial=2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[draw] (n1) {hello};
\node[right=of n1,draw] (n2) {hello2};
\node[draw,fit margins={left=3pt,right=12pt,bottom=3pt,top=8pt},fit=(n1) (n2)] (t31) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also employ the `positioning` library for easier positioning.

Comment: +1 It seems that small mammals cast long shadows and always know how to use tikz better than I! :)

Comment: @Andrew https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48273762#48273762

Comment: tikz doesnt recognize `fit margins` for me. I am using `positioning` library, and `fit` itself works ok. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Oh I see. you have created some kind of new command to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You can add some points to fit around. For example, to get

[image]

use the code:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={text=gray},node distance=2cm]
    \node[draw] (n1) {hello};
    \node[right of=n1,draw] (n2) {hello2};
    \coordinate[above left of=n1] (n1left);
    \node[draw,fit=(n1) (n1left) (n2)] (t31) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but let me recommend using the `positioning` library.

Comment: You can also include `shifts` into referenced coordinates in `fit` and forget creating auxiliar `coordinates`:  `\node[draw,fit={([shift={(-1cm,2cm)}]n1.north west) (n2)}] (t31) {};`

Answer (score 2):

[user194703's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523585/106882) is good, and works, and I up-voted it, and used the information in it, to write this answer. That said, what I am finding works for me is to use the settings user194703 uses in his/her macro, but use them directly, which settings are `yshift`, `xshift`, `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`, e.g:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, inner sep=0.2cm, node distance=0.6cm, fill=yellow!10]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \node [block] (sender) {sender};
    \node [block] (receiver) [right=of sender] {receiver};
    \node (agent) [
          fit=(sender) (receiver),
          yshift=-0.2cm, inner ysep=0.4cm,inner xsep=0.2cm,
          draw,
          label={[label distance=-1.0cm]190:agent}, rounded corners] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Sender receiver}
\end{figure}
```

Result:

[image]

(basically, the issue I found with the macro is I have to specify all four margins. the macros seems to me to be incompatible with using `inner xsep` etc myself, since the macro over-rides them).

Comment: This is actually the best and easiest answer.